# When using a separate MongoDB with meteor, meteor reset stopped working

Tags: mongodb, url, meteor, reset

I have my MONGO_URL set to mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor and have the MongoDB run as a service.

When running my project it seems OK to store data to the separate MongoDB until I tried to run meteor reset.

My assumption is it tried to remove its default database. The error complained that myproject.meteor\local is not empty and pointed to fs.js:456 which goes to files.js:256 (rm_recursive) and so on.

any idea what and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$ meteor reset` only resets the bundled MongoDB.  It won't reset an external Mongo database.

(That's something we should explain better in the documentation.)

In your case, try connecting to the Mongo database directly (with the `mongo` command line shell) and running `> db.dropDatabase()`

Comment: Is there some reason that meteor doesn't connect to the mongo database and issue this command rather than its current approach?  I can see how it might nuke databases outside of its responsibility, but both the reset and mongo commands have use outside of the default database. . .